# How can I make the UV map's shape look like the actual models?

Tags: uv

In 3ds max, there is the "normal mapping" button when you go into its UV editor, and "relax by polygon angles" option. Both of those help the uv map follow the shape of the model model, reduces islands too.

So for example, unwrapping with smart unwrap would give me many islands, but in 3ds max's case pressing the "normal mapping" button would produce fewer maps and they would follow the shape of the model

3ds max:

[image: Uv map of a low poly hand. 3ds max]

Blender (smart uv project):

[image: Uv map of a low poly hand. Blender]

[help.autodesk.com](https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2024/ENU/?guid=GUID-387A7C1A-B346-462A-A7B9-B881267EE49E):

> The Normal Mapping method of procedural mapping applies planar maps based on different vector-projection methods to texture polygons. It is the most straightforward method, but can result in even greater texture distortion than with the Flatten Mapping dialog. The Normal Mapping dialog lets you control how clusters are defined and mapped.

Comment: I don't remember what the 'normalize map' did in 3ds Max. As this is a Blender forum, obviously you should alway describe what it does when you're referring to a function of another software

Comment: Added an edit that hopefully explains better than I would.

Comment: So it's "normal mapping" and not "normalize map"?

Comment: Hi, Zeney_Dev. So there is conflicting terminology in the question. It's unclear what you are asking. You should edit the question and explain in more detail, what you want to achieve if you wish to get help. Or there is also another option. There is not much to it when it comes to UV mapping in Blender, you could also just learn pretty much everything about it in a couple of hours if you already have experience with 3d software. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/uv/index.html

Comment: It sounds like you want "project from view" under the UV Unwrap (U) menu.